# Generic Min and Max Lambda Function in C++

Tags: c++, generics, lambda, tuples, decltype

I am trying to create a lambda function, `lambdaMinMax`, which returns the min and max of a generic array as a tuple. I am trying to use `decltype` but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly:

```
 auto lambdaMinMax = [](const auto &v) {

    using vType = decltype(v[0]);

    vType min = numeric_limits<vType>::min();
    vType max = numeric_limits<vType>::max();

    auto iterBegin = v.begin();
    auto iterEnd = v.end();
    std::for_each(iterBegin, iterEnd, [&](const auto &a) mutable {
        min = [&]() -> auto { return a < min ? a : min; }();
        max = [&]() -> auto { return a > max ? a : max; }();
    });

    tuple<vType, vType> tupleRet(min, max);

    return tupleRet;
};

vector<double> vDouble;

for (double i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    vDouble.push_back(i);
}      

auto tupMinMax = lambdaMinMax(vDouble);

cout << "Min: " << get<0>(tupMinMax) << " Max: " << get<1>(tupMinMax) << endl;
```

When running the above code I get the error of `<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'vType '`. I believe this errors come from the two `numeric_limits` lines. Am I close or do I need to take a different approach?

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the answer. It makes it confusing to read the post, and frequently invalidates answers. The appropriate way of noting that an answer solved your problem is by marking it as accepted, which you have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
using vType = decltype(v[0]);
```

`vType` is deduced as `const double&`.

There is no appropriate specialization of [numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) class, so you have an error.

You might use [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) in order to make the code compile (in this case it removes reference and const qualifier):

```
using vType = std::decay_t<decltype(v[0])>;
```

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/g/2Pxx1F)

Comment: Yes this worked. I did realize that my overall design for `lambdaMinMax` is faulty and that using `numeric_limit` doesn't make sense to get the min and max of a vector, but `decay_t` helped me solve the question I asked.